# Is it possible to optmize this if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, optimization, enums

I have an `Enum` class called `Product` like this:

```py
class Product(Enum):
   HELMET = 1
   VEHICLE = 2
   CAR = 3
   TRUCK = 4
```

And i do some comparisons between two Products. As you can see, however, some items are "subcategories" of others (CAR and TRUCK can also be considered VEHICLE). In order to prevent bugs in my code, i came up with overriding `__eq__` method:

```py
class Product(Enum):
   CLOTH = 1
   VEHICLE = 2
   CAR = 3
   TRUCK = 4

   def __eq__(self, other):
      
      if not isinstance(other, Product):
         return False
      
      if Product.CLOTH not in (self.name, other.name):
         if Product.VEHICLE in (self.name, other.name):
            return True
         return False
      return self.value == other.value
```

- First, i compare if `other` is an instance of `Product`, returning false if it's not.
- Then, i check if one (or both) of the items to be compared are `CLOTH`.

  - If not, i check if one (or both) are `VEHICLE`.

    - If is, then i'm comparing `VEHICLE` with `TRUCK` or `CAR`, which is True.
    - If not, then i'm comparing `TRUCK` with `CAR`, which is False.
- If code reaches the final `return self.value == other.value`, it means that i'm comparing `CLOTH` with something else, so it's a basic check based in value of the `Enum`s.

I'd like to know if there's a better approach for this, or a way that i can optimize those `if` statements.

**Test outlines**

```py
Product.CLOTH == Product.VEHICLE # must return False
Product.CLOTH == Product.TRUCK # must return False
Product.CLOTH == Product.CAR # must return False

Product.CAR == Product.VEHICLE # must return True
Product.CAR == Product.TRUCK # must return False
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm quite confused by what you want here.

In general, overriding the `__eq__` is a bad idea. You don't have a lot of combinations here, I don't think you need this.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what comparisons you'd like, and what output you'd like please?

Comment: Sure, i will edit the question with some use cases.

Comment: I see. I don't really think it makes sense to do what you want there. It just doesn't make sense to use `Enum` for what is essentially a class structure. Have you though about making these classes? So you could have a `Vehicle` class, and `Car/Truck` inherit from it. Similarly with `Cloth` and `Helmet`. The you could use the built in methods of `issubclass`, which would make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

It would make more sense to use classes here I think

```
class Vehicle(object):
    pass

class Cloth(object):
    pass

class Car(Vehicle):
    pass

class Truck(Vehicle):
    pass

class Helmet(Cloth):
    pass

car = Car()
truck = Truck()
helmet = Helmet()

print(f"comparing car, Vehicle: {isinstance(car, Vehicle)}")
print(f"comparing truck, Vehicle: {isinstance(truck, Vehicle)}")
print(f"comparing truck, Car: {isinstance(truck, Car)}")
print(f"comparing helmet, Cloth: {isinstance(helmet, Cloth)}")
print(f"comparing helmet, Car: {isinstance(helmet, Car)}")
```

gives

```
comparing car, Vehicle: True
comparing truck, Vehicle: True
comparing truck, Car: False
comparing helmet, Cloth: True
comparing helmet, Car: False
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try a thing like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Product):
        return False

    if Product.CLOTH in (self.name, other.name):
        return self.value == other.value

    return Product.VEHICLE in (self.name, other.name)
```

Comment: This is good, but i just figured out a bug when i compare `Product.CAR == Product.CAR` or `Product.TRUCK == Product.TRUCK`, which is returning False instead of True.

Answer (score 0):

If the actual value is not important, you can encode your heirarchy in it:

```
class Product(Enum):
    CLOTH = '1'
    VEHICLE = '2'
    CAR = '20'
    TRUCK = '21'
    #
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return NotImplemented
        sv = self.value
        ov = other.value
        return sv.startswith(ov) or ov.startswith(sv)
```

and in use:

```
>>> Product.CLOTH == Product.CLOTH
True

>>> Product.CLOTH == Product.CAR
False

>>> Product.CLOTH == Product.VEHICLE
False

>>> Product.CAR == Product.VEHICLE
True

>>> Product.CAR == Product.TRUCK
False

>>> Product.TRUCK == Product.VEHICLE
True
```